# How to create a hash based on struct array types?

Tags: mapping, struct, keccak, data-types, type-casting

I have the following arguments to call a function in a smart contract:

```
    ERC20Reward[] calldata _erc20Rewards
    ERC721Reward[] calldata _erc721Rewards
    ERC1155Reward[] calldata _erc1155Rewards
    uint256 _nonce
    uint8 _v
    bytes32 _r
    bytes32 _s
```

What I want to do is to generate a hash with all of them, to check against a `mapping` that this exact signature has not been used before.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
    mapping(bytes32 => bool) signatures;

    bytes32 s = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
        _erc20Rewards,
        _erc721Rewards,
        _erc1155Rewards,
        _nonce,
        _v,
        _r,
        _s
    ));

    require(signatures[s] == false);
    
    signatures[s] == true;
```

The problem I am having with this is that `abi.encodePacked` does not accept any of these types: `ERC20Reward[]`, `ERC721Reward[]` and `ERC1155Reward[]` (struct arrays).

I am getting the following error: `Type not supported in packed mode.solidity(9578)`.

What should I do to be able to include these types in this call? Or is there any other way of achieving this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `abi.encode` instead, like this:

```
    bytes32 s = keccak256(abi.encode(
        _erc20Rewards,
        _erc721Rewards,
        _erc1155Rewards,
        _nonce,
        _v,
        _r,
        _s
    ));
```